# Find the point on graph of $xy=12$ that is closest to the point $(5,0)$

Tags: optimization

This is from a Derivatives chapter in the section on Optimization.

> Find the point on graph of $xy=12$ that is closest to the point $(5,0)$

I believe I have to use the distance formula. So, so far I have:

$y=12/x$

$d^2=f(x)=(x-5)^2 + ((12/x) - 0)^2$

$f(x)= x^2-10x+25+(144/x^2)$

$f'(x) = 2x-10-(288/x^3)$

$f'(x) = (x^3(2x-10)-288)/x^3$

$f'(x) = (2x^4-10x^3-288)/x^3$

$f'(x) = 2(x^4-5x^3-144)/x^3$

Here is where I am stuck. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you've set it all up correctly. That quartic polynomial doesn't have any nice roots, though.

Comment: Use the SOLVE button on a calculator.

Comment: I'd like to solve it without a cas.

Comment: Remember you're looking for $2(x^4-5x^3-144)/x^3 = 0$...

Comment: Yea, thats where I am stuck.  Any solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process of solving a general quartic equation analytically is described on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function). For your equation, the explicit answer turns out to be this:

[image: answer]

which evaluates to $\approx 5.75535$.

Are you still sure you want to find it without CAS?

Just to re-check that your equation is correct, I derived it differently. The tangent line at $(x,12/x)$ has slope $-12/x^2$. Hence, the normal line has the slope $x^2/12$. On geometric grounds, the normal line at the nearest point of the graph must pass through $(5,0)$. This gives the equation $$0-\frac{12}{x}=\frac{x^2}{12}(5-x)$$
which is $x^3(x-5)=144$, same that you got.

Most likely, the author of the textbook did not mean to create such a messy problem: it could be a typo or miscalculation on their part.

Comment: +1: Just because there is an analytic solution doesn't mean you want an analytic solution.